# How to disable the echo for cascalog queries

Tags: cascalog

it is a howto question. When I execute simple queries in the cascalog.playground area there is to much information. How to display only the results to (stdout).  What setting(s) do i need to update/change/add?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I could check on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cascalog-user/0zfM294498k
you can use the next form

```
(??<- [vars] & predicates)
```

And with that way you output the result as clojure seqs on the repl. Note that in the previous form you haven't to specify the output tap, because it will use the repl as output

More info in https://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog/wiki/Defining-and-executing-queries